# Denomination of dimensions in a 3D array

Tags: language-agnostic, matrix

Instances of this question are numerous on the internet, but I have not found a single satisfactory answer so far.

A 3-dimensional array has M x N x P elements, where

- M = no. of rows
- N = no. of columns
  and
- P = no. of ...?

Comment: Layers?  Floors?  Strata?

Comment: I like 'layers', but there must be an established term, or must there?

Comment: Randi hit on it ... I don't think there is a standard term if two of the three are rows and columns.

Comment: I'm upvoting Randi for his contribution, but you cannot call P in my question (an integer) "number of depth".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

height, width, and depth work nicely...

Comment: Thanks for the up-votes. I agree that this classification does not exactly fit into your framework "number of ...".

Answer (score 1):

Here is my vote

- Rows
- Columns
- Pages
- Books
- Libraries